# Bolding multiple words in JQuery UI Autocomplete without recursive HTML wrapping

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using JQueryUI's autocomplete fill in a textbox. This string can contain multiple words that I do a search on and return the search results to. I have already completed writing up about the retrieval of the autocomplete results across these multiple terms, and now need help bolding the words in my results.

For example, typing in "dog i" should result in the following results (ignore the bad spacing with the i's), where my three keywords are bolded:

"The **dog**  **i** s  a brown one."

"The brown  **dog**   **i** s   my fr **i** end."

The general solution seems to be using String.replace and a regex that adds some additional HTML wrapper to  the keywords in my results.  However, the issue is, because I have multiple keywords, I might run into the situation where I wrap the contents of the newly added HTML. Continuing the above example, the "i" would cause the "i" in "weight" of dog to get wrapped:

```
     "The brown <span style='font-we<span style='font-weight:bold'>i</span>ght:bold'>dog</span>  <span style='font-weight:bold'>i</span>s my fr<span style='font-weight:bold'>i</span>end."
```

How do I prevent my HTML from getting rewrapped by HTML? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    var regex;
    for (var i = 0; i < item.keywords.length; i++) {
        regex = new RegExp(item.keywords[i], "i");
        display = display.replace(regex, "<span style='font-weight:bold'>" +
            item.keywords[i] + "</span>");
    }
```

Comment: How does `"brown"` relate to `"dog i"`? and why isn't `"dog"` supposed to be bolded in the first string if the typed in text is `"dog i"`

Comment: @KevinB That was a misbold--thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: make a copy of the modified string, try the matches on the raw version and save in the clone string. why would the html rewrap your code, do you use html tag like regex strings in your replace function?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Bootstrap Typeahead jQuery plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead), it has this functionality

Comment: @lynnyi: So when you search for "dog i", it's the same as if you search for "dog" and "i" separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keywords = "dog i";
var text = "The brown dog i s my fr i end.";

var expression = $.map([keywords].concat(keywords.split(" ")), function(el) { 
  return "(?:" + el + ")";
}).join('|');

var regexp = new RegExp('(' + expression + ')', 'ig');
var filteredText = text.replace(regexp, '<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QPZhE/1/)**.

Comment: that's exactly that I'm looking for, using the power of smart regexes. Just a follow up question, I understand the (a|b|c) syntax looks for any of these alternatives.  What about the ?: syntax?

Comment: Glad I could help! `(?:stuff)` is a non-capturing group, i.e., it tells the regex engine not to capture/save the content of the group. It doesn't really matter much in this case, but since we are already capturing the *outer* group with `'(' + expression + ')'` there's no need to capture internal groups also.